# .NetCore 1.0 RC2 OpenXML Support

Tags: c#, .net, openxml, .net-core

**Can't find any appropriate package for working with Excel in my .NetCore 1.0 RC 2**

```
Package DocumentFormat.OpenXml 2.5.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp1.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0). Package DocumentFormat.OpenXml 2.5.0 supports: net (.NETFramework,Version=v0.0)
    One or more packages are incompatible with .NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0.
```

I am realy stuck with it. 
Search on the topic returned no results.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Currently Open XML libraries are not support for ASP.NET Core

Syncfusion File Format libraries for reading, writing and manipulating [Word](https://www.syncfusion.com/products/file-formats/docio), [Excel](https://www.syncfusion.com/products/file-formats/xlsio), [PDF](https://www.syncfusion.com/products/file-formats/pdf) and [PowerPoint](https://www.syncfusion.com/products/file-formats/presentation) files, will be capable of being used with ASP.NET Core 1.0 from their upcoming (June) release. Please create an thread in their [support system](https://www.syncfusion.com/support/directtrac) to get more details about it.

The whole suite of controls is available for free (commercial applications also) through the [community license program](https://www.syncfusion.com/products/communitylicense) if you qualify. The community license is the full product with no limitations or watermarks.

Note: I work for Syncfusion.

Comment: Actually i have solved problem by deploying additional app, based on .Net Framework, that handling Excel files, using existing library OpenXML

Comment: Hi Vijayakumar, I'd like to use MailMerge API. But since it's in Syncfusion.DocIO and that API seems not support .Net Core yet?

Comment: Hi Samuel, Yes, DocIO library supports performing Mailmerge, pls refer the below API links

https://help.syncfusion.com/cr/cref_files/file-formats/docio/Syncfusion.DocIO.Base~Syncfusion.DocIO.DLS.MailMerge~ExecuteGroup(MailMergeDataTable).html

https://help.syncfusion.com/cr/cref_files/file-formats/docio/Syncfusion.DocIO.Base~Syncfusion.DocIO.DLS.MailMerge~ExecuteNestedGroup(MailMergeDataTable).html


https://help.syncfusion.com/cr/cref_files/file-formats/docio/Syncfusion.DocIO.Base~Syncfusion.DocIO.DLS.MailMerge~ExecuteNestedGroup(MailMergeDataSet,List%7BDictionaryEntry%7D).html

Comment: https://help.syncfusion.com/cr/cref_files/file-formats/docio/Syncfusion.DocIO.Base~Syncfusion.DocIO.DLS.MailMerge~Execute(IEnumerable).html

https://help.syncfusion.com/cr/cref_files/file-formats/docio/Syncfusion.DocIO.Base~Syncfusion.DocIO.DLS.MailMerge~Execute(String[],String[]).html

Comment: Hi @Samuel  Also learnt that your requirement is removing merge fields after mail merge process and keeping only static text in Word document. In DocIO, merge fields will get removed automatically after mail merge process and only static text (merged values) will be there in the generated  Word document.

Please let me know if you need any further assistance.

Comment: Is there any syncfusion word library support for .net 1.1 and how soon might that be?