# Using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.DotNet.Core 1.0.1 to Export data to Excel

Tags: excel, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-1.0

I need to export data to Excel in My MVC Core (EF Core) Application.

I had a working code in MVC 6 (RC 1) before I upgraded to Core (see below).

```
public class ExcelFileResult : FileResult
{
    private object _model;
    private object _objT;
    private List<string> _columns;

    public ExcelFileResult(object model, List<string> columns, object objT) :
        base(new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"))
    {
        _model = model;
        _columns = columns;
        _objT = objT;
    }

    protected override Task WriteFileAsync(HttpResponse response)
    {
        var enumerable = _model as System.Collections.IEnumerable;
        if (enumerable == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("IEnumerable type required");
        }

        byte[] FileContents = null;
        using (MemoryStream mem = new MemoryStream())
        {
            using (var workbook = SpreadsheetDocument.Create(mem, DocumentFormat.OpenXml.SpreadsheetDocumentType.Workbook))
            {
                var workbookPart = workbook.AddWorkbookPart();
                workbook.WorkbookPart.Workbook = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Workbook();
                workbook.WorkbookPart.Workbook.Sheets = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Sheets();
                var sheetPart = workbook.WorkbookPart.AddNewPart<WorksheetPart>();
                var sheetData = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.SheetData();
                sheetPart.Worksheet = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Worksheet(sheetData);

                DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Sheets sheets = workbook.WorkbookPart.Workbook.GetFirstChild<DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Sheets>();
                string relationshipId = workbook.WorkbookPart.GetIdOfPart(sheetPart);

                uint sheetId = 1;
                if (sheets.Elements<DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Sheet>().Count() > 0)
                {
                    sheetId = sheets.Elements<DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Sheet>().Select(s => s.SheetId.Value).Max() + 1;
                }

                DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Sheet sheet = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Sheet() { Id = relationshipId, SheetId = sheetId, Name = "Sheet1" };
                sheets.Append(sheet);

                DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Row headerRow = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Row();

                var allProperties = _objT.GetType().GetProperties();
                var columns = _columns;

                List<System.Reflection.PropertyInfo> properties = new List<System.Reflection.PropertyInfo>();


                foreach (string column in columns)
                {
                    properties.Add(allProperties.FirstOrDefault(o => o.Name == column));
                }

                foreach (var property in properties)
                {
                    columns.Add(property.Name);

                    DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Cell cell = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Cell();
                    cell.DataType = DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.CellValues.String;
                    cell.CellValue = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.CellValue(property.Name);
                    headerRow.AppendChild(cell);
                }

                sheetData.AppendChild(headerRow);

                foreach (var item in enumerable)
                {
                    DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Row newRow = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Row();

                    foreach (var header in properties)
                    {
                        DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Cell cell = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Cell();
                        cell.DataType = DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.CellValues.String;

                        var value = header.GetValue(item);
                        cell.CellValue = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.CellValue(value?.ToString()); //
                        newRow.AppendChild(cell);
                    }
                    sheetData.AppendChild(newRow);
                }

                sheetPart.Worksheet.Save();
                workbook.WorkbookPart.Workbook.Save();
                workbook.Close();
                FileContents = mem.ToArray();

                return response.Body.WriteAsync(FileContents, 0, FileContents.Length);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I was using **DocumentFormat.OpenXml: 2.5.0**. Obviously, now the code is incompatible with **DocumentFormat.OpenXml.DotNet.Core 1.0.1** namespace. 
And I cannot install the OpenXml 2.5.0 package because is not compatible with dot net core.

Is there any sample code that I can use to Export to Excel in MVC Core?

Below is my **prject.json** file.

```
"dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
      "version": "1.0.0",
      "type": "platform"
    },
    "Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Tools": {
      "version": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
      "type": "build"
    },
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Design": {
      "version": "1.0.0",
      "type": "build"
    },
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": {
      "version": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
      "type": "build"
    },
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.UserSecrets": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink.Loader": "14.0.0",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Tools": {
      "version": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
      "type": "build"
    },
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGenerators.Mvc": {
      "version": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
      "type": "build"
    },
    "NuGet.CommandLine": "3.4.3",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity": "1.0.0",
    "Sakura.AspNetCore.Mvc.PagedList": "2.0.9",
    "Sakura.AspNetCore.PagedList": "2.0.1",
    "DocumentFormat.OpenXml.DotNet.Core": "1.0.1"},

  "tools": {
    "BundlerMinifier.Core": "2.0.238",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.SecretManager.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Tools": {
      "version": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
      "imports": [
        "portable-net45+win8"
      ]
    }
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "netcoreapp1.0": {
      "imports": [
        "dotnet5.6",
        "portable-net45+win8"
      ]
    }
  },

  "buildOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": true,
    "preserveCompilationContext": true
  },

  "runtimeOptions": {
    "configProperties": {
      "System.GC.Server": true
    }
  },

  "publishOptions": {
    "include": [
      "wwwroot",
      "Views",
      "Areas/**/Views",
      "appsettings.json",
      "web.config"
    ]
  },

  "scripts": {
    "prepublish": [ "bower install", "dotnet bundle" ],
    "postpublish": [ "dotnet publish-iis --publish-folder %publish:OutputPath% --framework %publish:FullTargetFramework%" ]
  }
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You can use Syncfusion apparently: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37871888/netcore-1-0-rc2-openxml-support

Comment: What about use DocumentFormat.OpenXml 2.9 (https://www.nuget.org/packages/DocumentFormat.OpenXml/) ??? It is .NET Standard compliant and you can you it in your net core project